# Update to a specific version with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I have already installed version 6.1 of elasticsearch and I want to update it to  aspecific version 6.8: how I can do that easy on my mac ?

I have already installed version 6.1 of elasticsearch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew can’t update to a specific version unless it has a formula (= package specification) for it. Regarding ElasticSearch, it has the following formulae:

```
$ brew search elasticsearch
==> Formulae
elasticsearch
elasticsearch@2.4
elasticsearch@5.6
```

The `elasticsearch` formula is currently installing ES 6.8.1:

```
$ brew info elasticsearch
elasticsearch: stable 6.8.1, HEAD
Distributed search & analytics engine
...
```

It means that if you want ElasticSearch 6.8, you just need to `brew install elasticsearch`.